# Can we use exit(0);

Tags: ios

*Can we use exit(0);* to quit our ios app on clicking a button in alert view and display a message in the same alert view saying, clicking on update your app will quit? **will that be accepted by apple, when my app goes for review?**

Comment: your app will be rejected,

Comment: Apple will reject your app. As per the apple guidelines, You should not kill the app from the code.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: Actually this is for force app upgrade.Can we write that method again in applicationWillEnterForeground method of app delegate?